# Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, facebook-oauth

I have already looked all the related answer in stackoverflow for this question but still couldn't find a working solution. Twitter and linkedin is working properly but for facebook I get this error,

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

Where do i put the link ? I did put this in Website with facebook login OPtion.

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/facebook/callback
```

Do i have to put these type of links at other place as well ?

Comment: Inside site url simply http://localhost:3000 works for me...

Comment: The error message you quote in your problem description is a completely different one that you have in the title …

Comment: I did change config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['AUTH_FB_KEY'], ENV['AUTH_FB_SECRET'] into config.omniauth :facebook,'AUTH_FB_KEY', 'AUTH_FB_SECRET' Might this work for it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the this [issue](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/21) on omniauth github page. Basically your problem is in facebook credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
I did change config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['AUTH_FB_KEY'],
 ENV['AUTH_FB_SECRET'] into
```

config.omniauth :facebook,'AUTH_FB_KEY', 'AUTH_FB_SECRET' 
     this work for it.